# PHP How to get the html raw code in this situation?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I want to get the text betweeen `<td valign="top" class="notizia_testo"></td>` from this url

http://www.ladige.it/news/2008_lay_notizia_01.php?id_cat=4&id_news=100152

I tried `simple html dom` and `php regular-expression`, but nothing returned. I checked the html raw code, and copied them as:

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOT
//all the html raw code
EOT;
preg_match_all("|<td valign=\"top\" class=\"notizia_testo\">([^^]*?)</td>|u", $str, $matches1);
print_r($matches1);
?>
```

I finally found the fault may be caused in:

```
line 762     <!?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/include/adv/manzoni_bigrect.php"); ?>
```

How to pass this line and work for me? Thanks.

Comment: What, if any, error message are you getting?

Comment: @mdm, I wanto get the text in `<td valign="top" class="notizia_testo"></td>`, `simple html dom` and `regular-expression` return nothing, and paste code between `<<<EOT ` ,call `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ... line 762`, do u have any idea?

Comment: `<!?php` Stray `!`. Is this copied from the code, or did you just add the php tag on SO to show that it's in a PHP block?

Comment: @Wiseguy, the copy from the code, you can check it by yourself, `http://www.ladige.it/news/2008_lay_notizia_01.php?id_cat=4&id_news=100152`

Comment: @yuli chika You should definately use `file_get_contents` as paulrajj suggests. No one uses the *heredoc* syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the results by simply using [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) as below,

```
    require 'simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php'; 

    $data = file_get_contents('http://www.ladige.it/news/2008_lay_notizia_01.php?id_cat=4&id_news=100152');
    $oHTML = str_get_html($data);
    $oTDs = $oHTML->find('table tr td.notizia_testo');
    $result = array();
    foreach($oTDs as $oTD) {
        $result[] = trim($oTD->plaintext);
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";
```